# Scripting for graphics

Tags: unix

Which are the recommended scripting languages for making graphics / pretty pictures in  a Gnu/Unix 
OS?

I would like to create 2-d and 3-d objects fast along with different things like shading them..
Does Python offer any support for doing such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are OpenGL bindings for [python](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), [lua](http://luagl.sourceforge.net/) and [ruby](http://ruby-opengl.rubyforge.org/) (and for nearly every other language). If you want to go with python, there are libraries like [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/), [Soya3D](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/soya3d/index.html)
and [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) (which by the way has also bindings for e.g. Perl, Ruby and others).